# Flush just an app not the whole project

Tags: python, django, django-models

`python manage.py flush` removes data from the entire project. I would like to be able to do `python manage.py flush agivenapp` How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

sqlclear management command can be helpful...

```
Usage: ./manage.py sqlclear [options] <appname appname ...>

Prints the DROP TABLE SQL statements for the given app name(s).
```

for the postgresql you can do:

```
./manage.py sqlclear myapp | psql dbname
```

**UPDATE**
for apps with migrations and Django 1.7+:

```
python manage.py migrate <app> zero
```

Comment: Unfortunately, sqlclear doesn't seem to be available for migrated apps (Django 1.8) ...

        "CommandError: App 'db' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations."

Comment: for apps with migrations and Django 1.7+: python manage.py migrate <app> zero

Comment: python manage.py migrate <app> zero followed by python manage.py migrate <app> worked for me... am I wrong in thinking I needed to reapply the migration?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with the `migrate` command which takes two positional arguments:

> Updates database schema. Manages both apps with migrations and those without.
>
> positional arguments:
>
> **app_label**
>   App label of an application to synchronize the state.
>   **migration_name**
>   Database state will be brought to the state after that
>   migration. Use the name "zero" to unapply all migrations.

So running a migrate zero followed by a migrate will clear only the data for the given app.

```
$ python manage.py migrate ${APPNAME} zero
$ python manage.py migrate ${APPNAME}
```

Answer (score 7):

For later versions of Django try in the Django shell:

```
from django.apps import apps
my_app = apps.get_app_config('my_app_name')
my_models = my_app.get_models()
for model in my_models:
    model.objects.all().delete()
```

More on the `apps` module can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/).
Of course, you could convert this to a management command yourself using the management [infrastructure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Much easier. Worked very well on 1.10.4. Thanks.  If migrations conflict this is best alternate.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed something to empty only certain apps. I came up with this solution. This worked for mysql. It could be that the code needs to be changed for other databases.

The main idea is not to do the whole 'flush'. Instead I get only what I want, with a grep from 'sqlflush'. You can also put everything in one line. For readability I split it up.

```
BEGIN="BEGIN; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"
TRUNCATE=`./manage.py sqlflush |egrep " \\\`app1_| \\\`app2_"`
END="SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; COMMIT;"

echo $BEGIN $TRUNCATE $END | ./manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: As of version 1.6 of Django the `TRUNCATE` command lists **all tables on the same line** so the script you are using here would **truncate everything**. Maybe earlier versions of Django put out one `TRUNCATE` per table but this is no longer the case.