# Django: How to reset single model/class database in app managing several different classes?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, class

Can django delete/erease/clean data of single database/class in an app managing more disjunctive classes? Or is it safer to build separate app for each separate/disjunctive database?

I have found how to delete all data from all project databases, i.e.:

```
python manage.py flush
```

I was only surpruised that user IDs and class IDs have not been reset to 1, but previously used ID numbers stayed somewhere in project memory.

I have also found that it is possible to delete/clean all databases of signle app, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766951/flush-just-an-app-not-the-whole-project) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273054/flush-single-app-django-1-9).

```
python manage.py migrate <app> zero
```

Here even IDs were reset. Does somebody know how to reset user IDs to start again from number 1?

But nowhere, I have found how to delete/erase/clean/reset  signle database/class of the app with more than one database. I have only found for [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730409/how-to-reset-database-for-specific-class) that there it could be possible like:

```
Model.delete_all
```

or

```
Model.destroy_all
```

But nobody confirmed there, that commads really work. Will/Can it work also in django?

Kind regards, Rene

Comment: How would you want to handle foreign keys from other tables that may be referencing the table you are reseting, should that table be reset too?

Comment: I do not have any cross-referencing tables now, so I do not need to hangle with foreign keys now. But I suppose that if I would like to delete a database with foreign keys referencing to other table/dtabase then most propably keys can be deleted when there will not be any data. But the organizing inter-conection between tables should be preserved for new data.

Comment: Is this something that you will want to run regularly? A migration that deleted the model and then recreated it would have the effect of "reseting" the table if you wanted to stick to python/django.  Which DB are you using and would raw DB commands be suitable?

Comment: Regularly not, but during the webpage development and testing quite often.  E.g. filing the database with fake data from the webpage GUI. I am using default sqlite3 database. I know I can use tests.py which will not save anything into the database, but I do not think it is possible to test everything with it during initial runnings.

Comment: Oh so this is just for local dev. You can just run `Model.objects.delete()`?